# Liquibase log level changing

Tags: java, logging, liquibase

I use code from https://www.liquibase.org/blog/3-ways-to-run-liquibase to run updates on DB. It works but produces a lot of logs. I tried to change the log level for Liquibase using

```
DefaultLoggerConfiguration defaultLoggerConfiguration = new DefaultLoggerConfiguration();
defaultLoggerConfiguration.setLogLevel("off");
```

but it doesn't help.

pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <mockito.version>3.3.3</mockito.version>
        <junit.version>5.6.2</junit.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>8.0.20</mysql.connector.version>
        <liquibase.version>3.9.0</liquibase.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.26</snakeyaml.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

May I reduce logs number without any additional dependencies?

Example of app https://github.com/Wismut/liquibase_h2_example

Comment: There are some existing questions about how to control the log level in Liquibase. Did you try any of those solutions?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I didn't find an answer to my question on the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WRONG ANSWER, see UPDATE section below

I think that you're trying to configure the Liquibase log level from Java code, as opposed to from Maven or something like that.

Your code doesn't work because you're creating a `DefaultLoggerConfiguration` object and setting a property but not making it available to Liquibase. It's just a random Java object and will go away as soon as `defaultLoggerConfiguration` goes out of  scope.

It looks like the right way to do this is to ask Liquibase to give you a reference to its configuration, then set the log level using that object.

```
LiquibaseConfiguration.getInstance()
    .getConfiguration(DefaultLoggerConfiguration.class)
    .setLogLevel("off");
```

UPDATE

Okay looks like that was totally wrong. The Liquibase logger is apparently a red herring. Possibly there was a way to configure it before, but now it just unconditionally delegates to SLF4J, which in your example on GitHub is using Logback as the actual logger.

By adding a file `src/main/resources/logback.xml` with the following contents I eliminated all but the info messages from your example.

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="liquibase" level="info"/>
    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

See http://logback.qos.ch/ for more information on how to configure Logback. Dropping a `logback.xml` file into the classpath is one way to configure, but you can use other strategies too.

Comment: Thanks for helping but it doesn't deal with logs. Moreover, I wrote 
```
LiquibaseConfiguration.getInstance()
                    .getConfiguration(DefaultLoggerConfiguration.class)
                    .setLogLevel("off");
            System.out.println(LiquibaseConfiguration.getInstance()
                    .getConfiguration(DefaultLoggerConfiguration.class)
                    .getLogLevel()); 
``` 
and I had OFF in the console and also a lot of logs

Comment: Okay. Somehow logging isn't working the way you think it is, then. Did you try setting the system property `liquibase.logging`?

Comment: If you can write the simplest possible program that (a) initializes Liquibase and then (b) performs some Liquibase operation that produces an unwanted log message, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: https://github.com/Wismut/liquibase_h2_example Produces more than 2400 log lines